# C - SDL2 window crash from simple animation loop

Tags: c, sdl

I am currently learning to use SDL2 in C and encountered a problem from which I couldn't find a solution so far

I am trying to run a simple 2 frames animation loop in the middle of the screen, but after a seemingly set amount of loops the window stops responding

```
while (1)
{
  SDL_RenderClear(window->renderer);
  test->o_update(sheet, test);
  SDL_RenderCopy(window->renderer, sheet->texture, &test->frame, &test->pos);
  SDL_RenderPresent(window->renderer);
  SDL_Delay(16);
}
```

The update function updates the coordinates on the sheet of the SDL_rect named "frame" in the test structure, so that it switches to the next frame every 30 frame. Every frame I SDL_RenderCopy, and SDL_RenderPresent to update the screen. Is there something blatantly wrong in my way of doing things ?

Comment: Where are your `SDL_PumpEvents()`/`SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_WaitEvent()` call(s)?

Comment: Indeed, I learned later on that you need to continuously poll events on SDL for it to keep responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came from the lack of wait/poll on SDL events, the process eventually stops responding in those cases.